# Proper use of 9 patch images

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-image

I am into layout design for my app to address multiple screen sizes. I referred the following documentations:

1. [Supporting Different Densities](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)
2. [Supporting Different Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)
3. [Icon Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html) and
4. [Draw 9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)

The more I read those documents, the more I became confused and convoluted. Although this might have been discussed here, I think I, at this point, need an expert advice.

What I found is that:

1. make one set of 9-patch images.
2. make adaptable layout and let Android stretch the 9-patch image for me.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's not that easy if you want to support most of the devices available; just one set of 9-patch images will not be enough, unless you use them only for background patterns.

You'll need at least one set of 9-patch images for each density folder, and together with a well-thought layout(maybe different for large and xlarge devices), and a good use of Fragments, you can manage to develop a nice looking app on most devices :)

Comment: Okay, that's slightly making sense. So, if I use Relative Layout, do I still go for different layout folders; for ldpi, mdpi and hdpi? I tried in ldpi and hdpi with the same layout. UI looked similar!

Comment: It's very possible to have only one layout and everything to looks right, and Relative Layout it's the best usually; I said you may want to have _different_ layouts for tablets and device, but it's not mandatory, it depends entirely on your design. And even if you have one layout or all, you might need to have multiple 9-patch images in the drawable ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi folders; for exemple a 200x300px 9-patch product image  in drawable folder will look perfect on all devices, but it might be too small for a tablet, and if you make it bigger, it might be too big for a ldpi device :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's correct. Adaptable layouts and 9-patch for backgrounds and simple images.

Note that if you have complex images maybe 9 patch are not well suited for it. Convert it to xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi and ldpi densities, and you're set.

Good look :)